# How to use phpunit installed from composer?

Tags: symfony, phpunit, composer-php

I want to start unit testing my symfony 2 application with phpunit. I installed phpunit using composer (per-project dependancy).
http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html

How do I now run the phpunit command on Zend Server? I don't have pear installed.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you followed the documentation, you have set the `phpunit/phpunit` dependency as a 'dev-dependency'.

If you don't have composer, you need to install it first. This is explained in the documentation: [Installation *nix](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-nix) or [Installation Windows](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows).
If you already installed composer, it is a good practise to update composer to the latest version by running the `self-update` command:

```
$ php composer.phar self-update
```

After your have done that, you need to install all dependencies, including the dev dependencies. This is done by running the `update` command with the `--dev` switch:

```
$ php composer.phar update --dev
```

All the dependencies are installed in the `vendor` directory. PHPunit runs from the console. Composer automatic put the console files inside the `vendor/bin` directory. You need to execute the `phpunit` file in there:

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit -c app/
```

The `-c` switch tells PHPUnit to look for the configuration file in the `app` directory, Symfony2 already set up the correct configuration to run all tests that are in the `<bundle>/Tests` directory.

## UPDATE (05-04-2013)

Composer has changed their update/install commands. `update` will install dev dependencies by default and if you want to install dev dependencies, you need to use the `--dev` option.

## UPDATE (11-06-2013)

Composer has changed their commands again, the `install` command will also install dev dependencies.

Comment: Aha! missed the --dev :p
Anyway, I get the following error now: `Warning: include(C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Ap
ache2\htdocs\project1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php): failed
 to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache
2\htdocs\project1\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php on line 150.` The file does exist though.

Comment: I continued my error here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765651/phpunits-textui-command-php-not-found

Comment: @WouterJ Did you mean "update will _not_ install dev dependencies by dafault"?

Comment: @Danack no, the update command will install dev dependencies by default

Comment: @WouterJ Er, looks like I need to run composer self-update again.

Comment: I ended up installing all these dependencies for PHPUnit to stop complaining: php-invoker, dbunit, phpunit-selenium and phpunit-story. Don't know why it needs all that.

Comment: @WouterJ, Regarding your updates, Why does composer keep changing their commands in non backwards-compatible ways?

Comment: @Pacerier the commands were changed once. And it was back in 2013, where Composer was still in early development.

Answer (score 24):

What about more composer way?

```
composer exec phpunit
```

It can be used for every binary file in vendor/bin directory.

Comment: Script phpunit handling the __exec_command event returned with error code 2

Answer (score 17):

**UPDATE (12-02-2014)**

Composer and PHPUnit have changed their commands again. 
The install command will also install dev dependencies:

Composer.json:

```
...
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
},
```

Run it:

```
$ composer.phar update --prefer-dist --dev
```

Now you can run your tests by:

```
$ bin/phpunit -c /app
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 13):

I like to define a script within `composer.json`, so that I can just run:

```
$ composer test
# ... runs phpunit
```

To do so, I need to modify `composer.json` to contain an entry like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": [
        "phpunit tests/*.php"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For Symfony 3 add `"phpunit/phpunit": "5.4.*"` to the `"require-dev"` section in your `composer.json` and run tests from the applications root directory with:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit tests
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed that. :)

Comment: Of course if you're using a legacy project layout, the command would be something like ./vendor/bin/phpunit src/AppBundle/Tests

Answer (score 5):

Add it as dev dependency, in your project directory:

```
composer require --dev "phpunit/phpunit=4.8.*"
```

The installed phpunit can now be executed with:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Comment: You can now use version: `5.3.*` instead.