# PHPUnit's TextUI/command.php not found

Tags: symfony, phpunit, composer-php

I installed phpunit for my symfony2 project following this:
[How to use phpunit installed from composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764309/how-to-use-phpunit-installed-from-composer/13764915#13764915)

But I get the following error now:

> Warning: include(C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\project1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\project1\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php on line 150

The file does exist and is in the autoload_classmap file, so I'm unsure why I receive this error when I run `vendor/bin/phpunit -c app`

Comment: Bounty started: another ref: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/744

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only should fix your basePath issue:
instead of this:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\project1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php`

it should be this :
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\project1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php`

You should go and read in line 150 of `composer\ClassLoader.php` and if possible add some `echo` or `var_dump` to debug and see the content of the variables used there that point to a wrong path.

Comment: That gives: `string(121) "C:\/www/project1/../../Program Files (x86)/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/proj
ect1/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php"`. The problem was I used a symlink. As soon as I updated composer not in the symlink directory, it updated the $baseDir correctly, and I could run the tests.

Answer (score 2):

`Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\`

show up twice in the include error but not the open stream error.

`open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\project1\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php on line 150`