# php unit first test symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to set some tests in symfony.
I am doing the first steps on that.
My question is from which folder should we write the phpunit -c app
I mean in c:/
or from the bundle
because I get the message of the not recognised internally command.

Comment: can anybody help me please. I still get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must run it from root direcory of your application. `app` is just an argument which specify folder where `phpunit.xml.dist` places.

Comment: you mean from my directory bundle??@forgottenbas

Comment: or from the tests directory in my bundle??

Comment: let me ask you if we should install something before begining testing with phpunit. I think everything is already installed.

Comment: You can specify folder that contain tests. Example you can run tests for one bundle `phpunit -c app src/A/BBundle/` or just one test `phpunit -c app src/A/BBundle/Tests/Controller/CControllerTest.php`

Comment: I mean I don't know the directory from which we initiate the command. Is it the vendor directory, the app or what is it exactly?

Comment: You mean in my Symfony directory. There I get the problem of not recognised command when trying phpunit -c app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764309/how-to-use-phpunit-installed-from-composer actually this answer resolved a part of the problem and when trying the same command in /vendor/bin I get this error message could not read app

Comment: I want to add also that I installed phpunit via the composer as a per project installation.

Comment: could not read "app" this is the error when I set the command from the vendor directory.

Comment: and when I set the command from the symfony directory I get the error of not recognised command internally and externally

Comment: could you help me please because when I want to run a particular test by writing this command vendor/bin>phpunit -c ../../app src/xxx/Bundle/tests/entity/yyy I get the error of could not read src/xxx/Bundle/tests/entity/yyy.php

Comment: `../../src/xxx/Bundle/tests/entity/yyy`

Comment: Itried /vendor/bin>phpunit -c ../../src/xxx/Bundle/tests/entity/yyy.php and I get the following message : could not load c:\wamp\www\symfony\src/xxx/Bundle/tests/entity/yyy.php Parse PI : PI php never end ... Start ttag expected, '<' not found

Comment: when I deleted the option -c it get me with the message Runtime exception : unable to guess the kernel directory . is that fine ?

Comment: and when trying /vendor/bin>phpunit -c ../../src/xxx/Bundle/tests/entity/yyy  and I get the following message : could not read "..\..\src/xxx/Bundle/tests/entity/yyy"