# setting phpunit command from the console symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have already posted this question on [php unit first test symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783576/php-unit-first-test-symfony)
I installed phpunit via the composer as a per project installation. 
When trying `vendor/bin>phpunit -c ../../app` every thing is ok and I get a positive answer.
Whereas this command give the answer to all the tests in the tests directory.

But I want the result to every test alone.
When trying  `/vendor/bin>phpunit -c ../../src/xxx/Bundle/tests/entity/yyy.php` and I get the following message : `could not load c:\wamp\www\symfony\src/xxx/Bundle/tests/entity/yyy.php Parse PI : PI php never end ... Start ttag expected, '<' not found`

and when trying `/vendor/bin>phpunit -c ../../src/xxx/Bundle/tests/entity/yyy` and I get the following message : `could not read "..\..\src/xxx/Bundle/tests/entity/yyy"`

Could anybody help me to know how should I write the command and from where execute it???
Any ideas???

Comment: should I add something to my path variable in order to make phpunit work properly??

Answer (score 12):

Don't use the `-c` option here. The `-c` option is a shortcut for `--configuration` and it points to the directory of a PHPunit configuration file (like `app/phpunit.xml.dist`). That configuration tells PHPunit where to look for the test classes and some other configuration, like the bootstrap file.

If you want to run tests for a specific test, you can do it like `phpunit path/to/tests/MyTest.php`. But you'll loose the autoloading then. To get that back, you can use the `--bootstrap` option to point to the bootstrap file. So it'll be `phpunit --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php path/to/tests/MyTest.php`.

If you want to run this command more often, you can better edit the `app/phpunit.xml.dist` file and create a new suite:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<phpunit ...>
    <!-- ... -->

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="MyBundle">
            <file>path/to/tests/MyTest.php</file>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <!-- ... -->
</phpunit>
```

And then run: `phpunit -c app --testsuite MyBundle`

Comment: but from where should I execute this command I mean from which directory?? shall it be the app one or the vendor one ??

Comment: @hjfcbHfhbv the project root

Comment: what does the project root mean??

Comment: The directory which contains the app, src, vendor and web directory

Comment: I get the following message 'phpunit' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. The the phpunit executable lives in the bin directory in the root. You need to run "bin/phpunit" (with quotes) while you're in the project root

Comment: Totally forgot about `-c`. Should **always** keep that in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Good for running in intellij as well. Change settings 'use alternative configuration file' and point to app/phpunit.xml.dist. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Happened with me too, but in fact we are misreading the documentation you are forgetting 'app' in the command line look:

```
phpunit -c app src/AppBundle/Tests/Util/CalculatorTest.php
```

Note the app parameter in command sentence.