# Including Symfony2 standalone console components packages in main app to access commands

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Standalone command app below works fine on its own when I call: `php console.php say:hello MyName`

The question is at the bottom.

**/var/www/html/local/test-app/composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "my/test-package",
  "description": "......",
  "type": "library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"": ""}
  },
  "require": {
    "symfony/console": "2.*"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

**/var/www/html/local/test-app/Command/HelloCommand.php**

```
<?php

namespace Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class HelloCommand extends Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('say:hello')
            ->setDescription('Say hello to someone')
            ->addArgument(
                'name',
                InputArgument::OPTIONAL,
                'Who do you want to say hello?'
            );
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $name = $input->getArgument('name');
        $hello = $name ? 'Hello '.$name : 'Hello';

        $output->writeln($hello);
    }
}
```

**/var/www/html/local/test-app/console.php**

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Command\HelloCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;

$application = new Application();
$application->add(new HelloCommand());
$application->run();
```

**QUESTION**

When I include standalone package in my main project's composer.json, composer installs everything but when I call `php console.php say:hello MyName` I get `Could not open input file: console.php` error. Obviously I have to create a symlink in `bin` directory like behat, phing, phpspec, doctrine etc. but how?

**my main project's composer json**

```
"require": {
    "my/test-package": "dev-master"
},
```

I've checked:

- [The Console Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html)
- [step-by-step how to use a single component in your project](https://www.talater.com/symfony_console_component/)
- [Symfony2 Components as standalone Packages](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony2-components-as-standalone-packages)
- https://github.com/exu/symfony2-console-standalone
- [Command line PHP using Symfony Console](http://www.sitepoint.com/command-line-php-using-symfony-console/)

So on....

Comment: I think no magic here, you're not in correct directory, or `console.php` have incorrect permissions.

Comment: This is irrelevant to anything Symfony related - you get that error whenever you invoke php with a non-existant file: `$ php DoesNotExist.php` outputs `Could not open input file: DoesNotExist.php`. Otherwise, check to make sure `console.php` has **read** permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I'm giving example in full so that anyone else can benefit from it.

**STANDALONE SYMFONY2 CONSOLE COMMAND APP**

**/var/www/html/local/test-app/composer.json**

After creating composer.json file below run `composer install`.

```
{
  "name": "my/test-package",
  "description": "Write something here",
  "type": "library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "Command": "src/"
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "symfony/console": "2.*"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "bin": [
    "bin/console"
  ]
}
```

**/var/www/html/local/test-app/bin/console**

Make sure to make it executable so run: `chmod +x bin/console` first.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

(@include_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php') || @include_once __DIR__ . '/../../../autoload.php';

use Command\HelloCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;

$app = new Application('My CLI Application', '1.0.0');
$app->add(new HelloCommand());
$app->run();
```

**/var/www/html/local/test-app/src/Command/HelloCommand.php**

```
<?php

namespace Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class HelloCommand extends Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('say:hello')
            ->setDescription('Say hello to someone')
            ->addArgument(
                'name',
                InputArgument::OPTIONAL,
                'Who do you want to say hello?'
            );
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $name = $input->getArgument('name');
        $hello = $name ? 'Hello '.$name : 'Hello';

        $output->writeln($hello);
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
test-app$ bin/console say:hello MyName
Hello MyName
```

Standalone console command app is ready now but you also want to use it in your main project so for that, do the following.

**YOUR MAIN PROJECT**

After including new package in your composer.json file, run `composer update my/test-package`.

**/var/www/html/local/my-main-app/composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "my/main-app",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "Main",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
          "type": "git",
          "url": "git@github.com:my/test-package.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        .......
        .......
        "my/test-package": "dev-master"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

If you look into your `bin` directory, you should see file called `console` so that means you can use the command in your main app.

**Test**

```
my-main-app$ bin/console say:hello MyName
Hello MyName
```

Answer (score 1):

Composer will install the dependencies in the <kbd>vendor</kbd>directory. You can use the full path to the <kbd>console.php</kbd> file:

```
php vendor/my/test-package/console.php say:hello MyName
```

It may look surprising to see the full path and not <kbd>vendor/bin/</kbd> only but this is a valid approach, as shown by [Wouter J with for PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13764915/2257664). It has one advantage: it will call the right command and not another time (eg. another package already created the <kbd>vendor/bin/console.php</kbd> file).

Comment: This sounds about right, but I'm holding skeptical because the question says that `console.php` is located at `/var/www/html/local/test-app/console.php`. Would there every be a reason for it to be installed outside of `vendor/`?

Comment: @HPierce you're talking about the main project, the user is trying to use it with composer in another project. (that's how I understood the question)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target a specific directory for binaries using composer use

```
{
    ....
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    ....
}
```

That lets you have a `bin` directory at the root of your project for all the binaries in it (since it creates the dynamic links for you automatically).

Don't forget to add this directory (`bin`) to your .gitignore file.

More info: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/vendor-binaries.md#can-vendor-binaries-be-installed-somewhere-other-than-vendor-bin-